# The structure of the uTorrent's uTorrentPartFile.dat

Tags: bittorrent, torrent

I'm trying to make a small utility that should automate some maintenance tasks of the `uTerrent`'s pool of torrents. To veryfy the hashes of partially downloded shares, I have to retrieve the parts of the pieces, that are not completely contained by the downloaded files, from the `~uTorrentPartFile_XXX.dat` file where `uTorrent` keeps them. This raises two questions:

1. Given a certain `.torrent` file, how do I compute the name of the corresponding `~uTorrentPartFile_XXX.dat` file (namely, the hexadecimal string that `uTorrent` uses instead of my **`XXX`**)
2. Where can I find information about the inner structure of the file that would allow me to retrieve the required data from it? Google's failed to help.

Comment: utorrent stores most of its state in bencoded files. so you can probably find metadata on the part files in the bencoded ones.

Comment: @the8472 The data that uTorrenr stores are in settings.dat and resume.dat. Their contents is quite clear. The former does not pertain to the shares, the latter, for each torrent, contains a bitmap indicating which parts are downloaded (among other things). The program I am writing reads and parses it. There's no info regarding the location of the parts there. The exact name of the partfile is not mentioned either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BiglyBT team has reverse engineered the ~uTorrentPartFile_XXXX.dat format when they created a migration plugin.
https://www.biglybt.com/download/utMigrate
https://github.com/BiglySoftware/BiglyBT-plugin-migratetorrentapp

From: https://github.com/BiglySoftware/BiglyBT-plugin-migratetorrentapp/blob/master/src/com/biglybt/plugins/migratetorrentapp/utorrent/PartFile.java

```
/**
 * uTorrent partfile
 * Basically, torrent data is split into 64k parts.  Header has 4 byte index for
 * each part, pointing to data if index is > 0.  
 * After the header is the 64k data chunks, first data chunk is 1, second is 2, etc. 
 * Last data chunk may be smaller than 64k.
 * 
 * ~uTorrentPartFile_*<hexsize>*.dat
 *   <Header>, <data>
 *   
 * hexsize
 *   torrent data length in bytes in hex with no leading 0
 *
 * Header
 *   <DataIndex>[<Num64kParts>]
 *   Raw header length = <Num64kParts> * 4
 *
 * Num64kParts
 *   How many parts is required if you split torrent data length into 64k sections. 
 *   ie. Math.ceil(torrent data length in bytes / 64k)
 *
 * DataIndex
 *   4 byte little endian integer.  Values:
 *      0 
 *        No data for this 64k part
 *      1..<num64Parts>
 *        1-based positional index in <data>
 *        Location in part file can be calculated with
 *          (Header Size) + ((value - 1) * 64k)
 *   
 * data
 *   <DataPart>[up to <num64kParts>]
 *   
 * DataPart
 *   64k byte array containing torrent data.  
 *   Bytes in <DataPart> that are stored elsewhere in real files will be 0x00. 
 *   ie. non-skipped files sharing the 64k part will be 0x00. 
 *   Last <DataPart> may be less than 64k, which means the rest of the 64k would
 *   be 0x00 (and part of a non-skipped file)
 *     
 */
```

---

#### Bonus

There is also some useful information about the content in **resume.dat** and **settings.dat** in the code comments here:

https://github.com/BiglySoftware/BiglyBT-plugin-migratetorrentapp/blob/master/src/com/biglybt/plugins/migratetorrentapp/utorrent/ResumeConstants.java
https://github.com/BiglySoftware/BiglyBT-plugin-migratetorrentapp/blob/master/src/com/biglybt/plugins/migratetorrentapp/utorrent/SettingsConstants.java